# How to implement Google's DoubleClick Ads in an android application?

Tags: android, double-click, ads

How do we implement google's double click for displaying ads in our android application?
Can someone provide me steps that needs to be followed to implement the same.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check this link -

```
 http://code.google.com/mobile/afma_ads/docs/
```

it explains it all (well most of it to get started!)

I went on a similar path looking for a ad serving support in my android app - eventually I settled for Mobclix - I am happy :-)  Check the question I had posed at

```
 Serving Ads in Android App -
```

Comment: My requirement is to implement DoubleClick.